# Генерация чисел

Tags: алгоритм

Допустим у меня есть число 5 , мне нужно сгенерировать числа с погрешностью +- 2, что бы их среднее арифметическое было равно 5 (например: 3 6 5 4 7 5)

Comment: Задача поставлена нечетко. Нужно, чтобы числа были целыми? Как они должны быть распределены - равномерно, или ближе к нормальному? Или еще как? И сколько должно быть чисел - много или мало?

Comment: В общем как целыми, так и дробными, в зависимости от условия. Ближе к нормальному. Мало

Answer (score 3):

1. Суммируете 12 чисел rand(0,1). Поскольку каждое имеет матожидание 0.5, m = 6.
2. Вычитаете 6 и получаете V c m = 0.
3. Поскольку дисперсия каждого 1/12, дисперсия суммы = 1.
4. x = V * D + M, где D = 4, а М = 5.
5. Ах, да забыл - 3 > X > 7 удаляем.

Имеется еще один строгий прием генерации НРЧ:

генерим 2 rand(0,1) a1 и a2. И получаем 2 НРЧ с М = 0 и D = 1:

```
v1 = sqr(-2ln(a1))*cos(2*pi*a2) 
v2 = sqr(-2ln(a1))*sin(2*pi*a2)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант в лоб.** С помощью rand генерим случайные числа в нужном диапазоне. Но генерим на одно число меньше, чем нужно. Паралельно с генерированием чисел суммируем разницу между текущим числом и 5 (нам ведь нужно, что бы среднее было для него). Если генератор случайных чисел работает хорошо, то в конце поправка будет небольшой и можно будет ее можно будет учесть. Но может так произойти, что она будет больше 2 или меньше -2. А это уже хуже. Но ведь никто не мешает по ходу генерирования добавить скорректировать два последних числа или три.

**Способ другой.**

Генерируем тем же способом. Но если разница выходит за допустимый диапазон, то добавляем одно число от себя - корректирующее, что бы подогнать разницу.

**Способ три.**

Нужное кол-во чисел делим на 5 (у нас же могут быть числа 3,4,5,6 и 7). Наполняем массив числами (можно по циклу, можно последовательно), что бы в массиве оказалось приблизительно равное кол-во разных чисел. Если нацело не делиться, то можно исключить 5 или 4 и 6. Потом применяем любой алгоритм перемешивания.

**Способ 4**

Любым известным способом перемешиваем пятерку чисел и отдаем, потом следующий раз мешаем и отдаем.

Answer (score 1):

я тут код набросал :) думаю он работает по одному из алгоритмов которые описали другие :)

```
public class PseudoRandomGenerator
{
    // this is a delta multiplier, which determine speed
    // of moving generated numbers average to the expected value
    private static final double AVERAGING_SPEED = 0.5 ;
    // ^^ reasonable values are: 0.1 - 2.0

    /*
     * fields initialized with input parameters 
     * or by values generated based on the input parameters
     */
    private double average ; // expected average
    private double lower ; // lower bound of allowed values
    private double upper ; // upper bound of allowed values
    private double window ; // bounds diff

    // default number generator
    private Random random = null ;

    /*
     *  store generator state
     */
    private double delta = 0 ; // overall diff against expected average

    public PseudoRandomGenerator ( int average, int offset, long seed )
    {
        this.average = average ;

        this.window = 2 * offset ;
        this.lower = average - offset ;
        this.upper = average + offset ;

        random = new Random ( System.currentTimeMillis () + seed ) ;
    }

    public PseudoRandomGenerator ( int average, int offset )
    {
        this ( average, offset, 0 ) ;
    }

    public int next ()
    {
        // generate random number
        // 1) generate random number in bounds window
        // 2) adjust it with lower bound offset
        // 3) apply averaging delta
        double result = random.nextDouble () 
                * window + lower - delta * AVERAGING_SPEED ;

        // round up result
        result = Math.round ( result ) ;

        // prevent missing limits
        if ( lower >= result )
        {
            result = lower ;
        }
        else if ( upper <= result )
        {
            result = upper ;
        }

        // adjust generation diff
        delta = delta - (average - result) ;

        return (int) result ;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // TODO: change number of numbers to generate
        int count = 15 ;

        // init generators

        // uses default seed
        PseudoRandomGenerator g1 = new PseudoRandomGenerator ( 5, 2 ) ;

        // custom seed
        PseudoRandomGenerator g2 = new PseudoRandomGenerator ( 5, 2, 15000 ) ;

        // generate numbers
        boolean first = true ;

        double mid1 = 0 ; // total average
        double mid2 = 0 ; // total average

        System.out.println ( "generator\t/ random \t/ random average (overall)" ) ;

        for ( int i = 0, j = 1 ; i < count ; i++, j++ )
        {
            int random1 = g1.next () ;
            int random2 = g2.next () ;
            if ( first )
            {
                mid1 = random1 ;
                mid2 = random2 ;
                first = false ;
            }
            else
            {
                mid1 += random1 ;
                mid2 += random2 ;
            }

            System.out.println ( "generator 1\t/ " + random1 
                    + "\t\t/ " + (mid1 / j) ) ;
            System.out.println ( "generator 2\t/ " + random2 
                    + "\t\t/ " + (mid2 / j) ) ;
            System.out.println () ;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант только-целых**
Генерить их попарно: центр+offset, центр-offset. Поместить все в один массив, перемешать порядок.

**Вариант с дробными**
Полагаемся на нормальное распредление и не читаем «Чёрный лебедь» Талеба. Сложив 6 случайных с линейным распределением и разделив на 6, получаем приближённый «нормальный» колокол с центром посередине. На php:

```
$Vn = ( rand(5-2,5+2) + rand(5-2,5+2) + rand(5-2,5+2) + rand(5-2,5+2) + rand(5-2,5+2) + rand(5-2,5+2) ) / 6;
```

Так можно набрать сколь угодно много значений, не волнуясь о том, что финальное корректирующее значение может оказаться больше 2. Итак, набираем по этой формуле N-1 случайное значение, считаем их среднее арифметическое, и последним добавляем разницу 5 и полученного с.а.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего, видимо, так:

1. Генерируем произвольные 5 чисел в промежутке от 0 до 1.
2. Смотрим на разброс этих чисел (максимальное минус минимальное). Если он недостаточен, домножаем все числа на константу, чтобы он стал каким надо.
3. Вычисляем среднее арифметическое. Если оно не 5, прибавляем ко всем числам константу, чтобы стало 5. При этом разброс не поменяется.

Вот и всё.