# Преобразование Бокса — Мюллера

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, математика, теория-вероятностей

Хочу воспользоваться [первым вариантом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) этого метода, чтобы генерировать псевдослучайные числа с нормальным распределением.

Метод может сгенерировать два псевдослучайных числа, но мне нужно только одно. Могу ли я использовать только одну из этих формул (только с синусом или только с косинусом)? Будет ли распределение столь же нормальным, как если использовать их обе?

Код на C++:

```
const float pi = 3.1415926535;

float RandomFloat()
{
    return (float) rand() / RAND_MAX;
}

float normalRand()
{
    float z = RandomFloat();
    float f = RandomFloat();

    float r = cos(2 * pi * f) * sqrt(-2 * log(z));

    return r;
}
```

Я понимаю, что это недоиспользование возможностей алгоритма, что программу можно было бы оптимизировать, но мне не нужна такая большая производительность.

Comment: Ну если уж у вас С++ - почему не воспользоваться библиотекой <random>?

Comment: В вашем коде до вызова `rand()` надо вызывать `srand()` - иначе генерации непроизойдет, Сид не инициализирован.

Comment: @Harry а в ней есть функция нормального распределения? Вообще знаю про std::normal_distribution, но использовать не хочу.

Comment: @NewView я в курсе про srand(), он вызывается перед обращением к этим функциям, просто не здесь, а в main()

Comment: @NewView Что за ерунду вы про `srand`говорите? Произойдет, только и того, что при разных запусках будет одна и та же последовательность чисел. А вообще, от `rand` все в один голос предлагают отказываться...

Comment: "А вообще, от rand все в один голос предлагают отказываться..."
почему, и что использовать вместо него?

Comment: См. мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: @Harry, А одна и та же цифра не означает что он ничего не сгенерит? И результат его работы будет не пригоден к использованию? Функция srand() используется для установки начала последовательности, генерируемой функ­цией rand() (функция rand() возвращает псевдослучайные числа).

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB/164911#164911) тоже посмотрите. Там все попроще, но надежно.

Comment: @NewView Tckb не верите - запустите сами. Если НЕ вызовите `srand` или будете вначале вызывать с одним и тем же числом - то при каждом запуске программы просто будут идти одни и те же числа, только и всего. Удобно для отладки :)

Answer (score 3):

**1)**
Из прикреплённой Вами же ссылки можно сделать вывод, что можно использовать и одно число:

> Тогда z 0 и z 1 будут независимы и распределены нормально с математическим
>   ожиданием 0 и дисперсией 1. При реализации на компьютере обычно
>   быстрее не вычислять обе тригонометрические функции — cos ⁡ и sin ⁡— а рассчитать одну из них через другую.

Основное тригонометрическое тождество: **sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) = 1**;
Выведите из него одно или пару случайных чисел.

**2)** Используйте `srand` от времени на Вашем компьютере, так возвращаемые значения `rand()` будут всегда разные.
Пример:

```
    srand( time( 0 ) ); // автоматическая рандомизация
    cout << "rand_value = " << 1 + rand() % 10 << endl;
    // rand()%10 - возвращает значения от 0 до 9.
```

**UPD1:**

Подозреваю, что Преобразование Бокса — Мюллера здесь не зря используется и Вам нужно 2 величины. На всякий случай оставлю ссылку на небольшую статейку:
[тык](https://habr.com/post/208684/).

**UPD2:**

Пояснение почему можно использовать любую из двух формул для просто случайного числа с "нормальным" распределением:
Формулы отличаются лишь косинусом и синусом. И косинус, и синус принимают значения от -1 до 1. Это полученное значение мы умножаем на одно и то же выражение.

Comment: Википедия - такой себе источник информации, тем более без ссылок на первичные источники, поэтому и спрашиваю у профессионалов.

Comment: @havon, не стоит питать иллюзий, что здесь отвечают некие «профессионалы»... в большинстве это такие же скучающие люди, как и те, что правят вики ;)

Comment: @havon Вот ссыль на англоязычную вики с теми же формулами, но чуть подробнее и с бОльшим количеством источников:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform

Answer (score 3):

Экспериментируем...

10000 пар чисел и 20000 первых чисел загоняем в Wolfram Mathematica и просим построить две гистограммы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похоже на то, что вполне можно использовать только одно число.

Можно и детальнее, разницы нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рекомендуемый вариант -

```
int main()
{
    random_device rd{};
    mt19937 gen{rd()};
    normal_distribution<> d{0,1};

    for(int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i)
        cout << d(gen) << " ";
}
```

Гистограмма, впрочем, такая же :)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а это данные сгенерированные кодом на вольфраме? он плавающую точку использует и если да, то какую? и можно сам колокол поверх этого наложить?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Нет, это я просчитал своей программой, а уже вывод запихал в вольфрам.

Answer (score 1):

> Могу ли я использовать только одну из этих формул (только с синусом или только с косинусом)? Будет ли распределение столь же нормальным, как если использовать их обе?

Да, но практичней будет вычислять оба и второе значение использовать при последующих запросах к функции.

Но следует иметь ввиду, что это не очень хороший генератор (как и все наивные варианты использования `rand()`) — для типового размера `RAND_MAX` в `32768` этот алгоритм не будет выдавать результаты ≥4.57... да и у меньших значений статистика наверняка испортится.